# sleep of non-blocking calls

Tags: python, sockets, nonblocking, thread-sleep

I am looking for an optimum sleep value to receive data from a non-blocking socket. E.g:

```
while True:
    data=s.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        time.sleep(10) #10ms
    else:
        pass #...
```

No sleep would lead into 100% CPU usage, so any idea how to get the best CPU Usage and bandwith? How long has a sleep to be so the CPU can do a thread switch?

Btw, does it make sense to set the buffer of the socket via SO_SNDBUF/SO_RECVBUF and set TCP_NODELAY or shouldn't they be combined?

Comment: Unlearn the pattern. Now! Forget that a function `sleep()` ever existed. For each use of `sleep()` there is another, more appropriate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing that yourself. Use the [select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) call, with a timeout if you need your code to wake up every so often even if no data was received.

BTW, TCP_NODELAY is of the sending side, won't influence your `read`s.

Comment: In my case the socket switchs read/write calls. recv/send/send/send/recv/recv/...

Answer (score 3):

If you plan to use `sleep()`, why don't you just use blocking sockets?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html). It will basically pause the program and wake it up when there is data available on the socket.

Comment: I thought when I use select(...) the data can be gone in a nonblocking socket when I return and try to receive it.

Comment: @Mister No. Where did you get that idea? You cannot lose data via any API to TCP/IP unless you perpetrate programming errors.